# I've deployed a database project to my local SQL Server Express - how do I see the database now?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I've created a "Database project" (.dbproj project file) in Visual Studio 2008, added a couple of tables there and selected "Build->Deploy". Visual Studio said it has successfully deployed my `Database1.sql` into `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`.

Now I'd like to see the database - be able to delete it or just see that it looks right - but I can't find where the database is and how to manipulate it without writing code. How can I get a hold on the newly created database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL Server Management Studio stand alone application, or the Server Explorer in Visual Studio.
There are also a lot of tools from other vendors like Toad or SQuirreL...